# Export pst files and index

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, pst

Is there a way to export PST files into a somewhat "open" format, and then use some sort of freeware to index the emails and then search upon the emails in a fast manner?  Basically, I have about 4 PST files from the past year or so.

What I'm trying to accomplish is, not being bound by Outlook to open (or keep open) the PST files and that was I can either:

1. move the files onto a file server or
2. keep them in a shared directory and use some sort of application to search upon the contents of the emails very fast.

This might not exist, and that's fine, but I just didn't know if someone has had experience in trying to do this.

Comment: Not free, but look [here](http://superuser.com/a/484621/138343).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Windows provided built-in Desktop Search, I previously had good results with the free [Copernic Desktop Search](http://www.copernic.com/en/products/desktop-search/index.html).

Its [File Types](http://www.copernic.com/en/products/desktop-search/features-file-types.html) page says that it searches:

> Outlook (versions: 2000, XP, 2003, 2007, 2010)

I *think* that it indexes email content, as well as things like sender, subject and date - but it would be worth testing out.

Their blog posting of July 2012 ([Version 3.6 is now available!](http://blog.copernic.com/index.php/2012/version-3-6-is-now-available/)) says that:

> Outlook emails are now printable even if Outlook is closed.

So I'd imagine you could probably view them when it's closed too.

Comment: Sweet!  I'll try this out tomorrow to see what results it yields.